# javascript capture everything between img src " ... "

Tags: javascript

Hi i would like to capture everything between img src="...", however not sure why the code below is not working

```js
var stringHtml = '<img src="content://media/external/images/media/21260"><img src="content://media/external/images/media/21260"><img src="content://media/external/images/media/21260">';
var srcArray = ['x.png', 'y.png', 'z.png']

var rgx = /<img src="([^"]+)"/g;
var match;

for (var a = 0; a < srcArray.length; a++) {
  match = rgx.exec(stringHtml);
  stringHtml = stringHtml.replace(match[1], srcArray[a]);
}

alert(stringHtml);
```

Comment: "not working" is not a good explaination about the problem.

Comment: Please provide more detail about what error is occuring and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: debug and see what is happening: `match = rgx.exec(stringHtml);
  console.log(match, stringHtml)`

Comment: basically im trying to capture everything in my img src="..." in stringHTML and replace that with elements in scrArray, however, when there are / and more than a number of characters it show as invalid java.

Comment: What do you expect `alert(stringHTML)` to produce?  What is it currently producing?  If there is an error, provide the actual error message please, because "invalid java" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: don't you need `'` around your regex?  i.e. `var rgx = '/<img src="([^"]+)"/g';`?

Comment: the outcome should be - stringHtml = '<img src="x.png"><img src="y.png"><img src="z.png">';

Comment: @Claies thats still giving me an error

Comment: giving you **what** error?  multiple people have tried to say, post the error code ***in the question body***.  That being said, I agree with @bambam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like answered so often, [don't use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not). Instead, parse the string and easily and reliable get the src

```js
var stringHtml = '<img src="content://media/external/images/media/21260"><img src="content://media/external/images/media/21260"><img src="content://media/external/images/media/21260">';

const parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(stringHtml, 'text/html');

for (let img of parser.getElementsByTagName('img')) {
  console.log(img.src);
}
```